# Adding filter in a related module field in vtiger 6.0

Tags: php, module, vtiger

First,I am creating a module that has two fields (example: Name, Type). After that i created another module where there is a related module field(the first module that i've created).Now my problem is, I want to add filter in the related module field wherein, I can only view those names which type is the type that i want. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

If you check the popup URL, you have to pass new parameter with name of the field that is type=value and fetch that in PHP file. Vtiger will automatically add that parameter to query. You have to pass parameter from .js file.